# How to add Catalog , categories with Products in in Sitecore eCommerce programatically

Tags: sitecore-commerce

The below code is not working for me. Any thing is missing?

```
            Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            var result = await _createSellableItemPipeline.Run(new CreateSellableItemArgument(random.Next().ToString(), "Hussain Test Product name", "Product display name", "This is a description of my test product"), context);
            SellableItem addedItem = null;
            if (result != null) // Null here means it failed to add
            {
                addedItem = result.SellableItems.FirstOrDefault(); 
                addedItem.ParentCatalogList = "{59DDADC1-9B88-727E-9E14-3F6CF321AE0F}";
                addedItem.ParentCategoryList = "{871C3B62-CE96-AD61-DABE-10DB020F02C5}";
                addedItem.Brand = "MyTest Brand";
                addedItem.Manufacturer = "My Manufacturer";
                var saveResult = _persistEntityPipeline.Run(new PersistEntityArgument(addedItem), context);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there.

You need to create the relation between the product and the catalog

```
   var relation = await _createRelationshipPipeline.Run(
                 new RelationshipArgument(categoryID, addedItem.Id, "CategoryToSellableItem")
                      {
                      Mode = new RelationshipMode?(RelationshipMode.Create)
                      }, context);
```

The categoryId should look in this way : **Entity-Category-catalogname-categoryname**

To create a category you need to use next code:

```
 var createCategoryCommand = this._commerceCommander.Command<CreateCategoryCommand>();
 var createdCategory = await createCategoryCommand.Process(context.CommerceContext, "catalog id", "category name", "category displayname", "description");
```

CommerceCommander is declared on your class :

```
 private readonly CommerceCommander _commerceCommander;
```

and is injected on your constructor :

```
     public YourPipelineBlock(CommerceCommander commerceCommander)
     {
         this._commerceCommander = commerceCommander;
     }
```